# DBGridEh Field LookupParams property does not post data to database

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, dbgrid

I am using the DBGridEh (ascendant of DBGrid) Field LookupParams property and surprise that this is not posting the data to database. It is shown in the grid but not posting.

I am really not sure if this is the behavior of the LookupParams property but I would like to post the data being displayed.

Anyone of you familiar with this?

Below my RME:

[image: Sample Form]
[image: LookupParams Setup]
[image: Dropdown Listsource]

```
unit Unit9;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, DBGridEhGrouping, ToolCtrlsEh,
  DBGridEhToolCtrls, DynVarsEh, Data.DB, Datasnap.Provider, MemDS, DBAccess,
  Uni, EhLibVCL, GridsEh, DBAxisGridsEh, DBGridEh, Datasnap.DBClient,
  UniProvider, MySQLUniProvider, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    ucntest: TUniConnection;
    muptest: TMySQLUniProvider;
    cdstest: TClientDataSet;
    dbgrdhtest: TDBGridEh;
    uqtest: TUniQuery;
    dsptest: TDataSetProvider;
    dstest: TDataSource;
    dbgrdhtest1: TDBGridEh;
    cds1: TClientDataSet;
    uq1: TUniQuery;
    dsp1: TDataSetProvider;
    ds1: TDataSource;
    strngfldcds1ListID: TStringField;
    strngfldcds1Name: TStringField;
    strngfldcds1AccountNumber: TStringField;
    btntest: TButton;
    procedure btntestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm9.btntestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if MessageDlg('Do you wish to save the Manpower Services changes?',
           mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes then
      begin
        cds1.ApplyUpdates(0);
      end;
end;

end.
```

Update: Result on MySQL Table

[image: MySQL Database Table Query]

Comment: What do you mean by "not posting"?  Which data are you expecting to be posted in which column of which table?  Btw, your code seems wrong, because of the two calls to `cds1.ApplyUpdates`.  you only need one, because if it succeeds, there will be no changes to apply in the second call, whereas if the first call fails, calling it again is unlikely to succeed - if you are trying to force the changes to be applied, why not just do it in the first call?

Comment: @MartynA I did not notice redundancy. I already removed the second call. Regarding the column that is not posting, I am referring to ListID. I have updated the question attaching the screenshot of my table query.